# Performance problems on historical data - inner join using mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two tables one containing products(`produits`) and one containing sales (`ventes`) which contains millions of records on which I am performing an inner join. This is really slow.

Following is an example query. The `WHERE` clause can contain more fields describing the products (`upc`, `category`, etc.) depending on what the user wants.

```
use mysql_reception;
SELECT p.upc, p.description, sum(v.quantity)  
FROM produits p inner join ventes v on p.upc = v.upc    
WHERE v.date > '2021-01-01' and date < '2021-04-30' and p.sap = "32015201"
GROUP BY p.upc;
```

I have an index on the columns

- sap
- date and upc
- date

It takes minutes to get the result.

I was wondering if I should create a third table that contains all the historical data so no inner join is required when I query the data or is this bad? Is there a better solution to increase performance?

EDIT 31-05-2021 :

### On database

Column date is on table Ventes (Sales)

Column sap is on table Produits (Products)

Both tables have a upc column for the join.

This is used by humans so I'd like a 10 seconds execution.

### Configuration

OS : Windows Server 2012

RAM : 6 Gb

CPU : Intel Xeon E5-2660 @ 2.2GHz

MySQL version 8.0.21

### Plan

[image: Execution plan]

[image: Explain]

```
{
"query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
        "query_cost": "452260.74"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
        "using_temporary_table": true,
        "using_filesort": false,
        "nested_loop": [
            {
                "table": {
                    "table_name": "p",
                    "access_type": "ref",
                    "possible_keys": [
                        "IX_upc",
                        "IX_sap"
                    ],
                    "key": "IX_sap",
                    "used_key_parts": [
                        "sap"
                    ],
                    "key_length": "48",
                    "ref": [
                        "const"
                    ],
                    "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
                    "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
                    "filtered": "100.00",
                    "cost_info": {
                        "read_cost": "1.00",
                        "eval_cost": "0.10",
                        "prefix_cost": "1.10",
                        "data_read_per_join": "736"
                    },
                    "used_columns": [
                        "pharmacieIdBJC",
                        "upc",
                        "sap",
                        "idItem",
                        "description",
                        "coutant"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "table": {
                    "table_name": "v",
                    "access_type": "ALL",
                    "possible_keys": [
                        "IX_DATE_UPC"
                    ],
                    "rows_examined_per_scan": 4207042,
                    "rows_produced_per_join": 1985946,
                    "filtered": "47.21",
                    "using_join_buffer": "hash join",
                    "cost_info": {
                        "read_cost": "253665.04",
                        "eval_cost": "198594.60",
                        "prefix_cost": "452260.74",
                        "data_read_per_join": "378M"
                    },
                    "used_columns": [
                        "id",
                        "Date",
                        "upc",
                        "quantite",
                        "coutMoyen",
                        "montantVente"
                    ],
                    "attached_condition": "((`mysql_reception`.`v`.`Date` > DATE'2021-01-01') and (`mysql_reception`.`v`.`Date` < DATE'2021-04-30') and (`mysql_reception`.`p`.`upc` = convert(`mysql_reception`.`v`.`upc` using utf8)))"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are leaving out the 1st and 30th of the month? Or is it a DATETIME, in which case you are leaving out midnight of the 1st and all of the 30th?  I suggest

```
WHERE v.date >= '2021-01-01'
  and v.date  < '2021-01-01' + INTERVAL 3 MONTH
```

That works "correctly" regardless of the datatype.  (And it handles leap year, year wrap, etc.)

*Add* this flipped index:

```
INDEX(upc, date)
```

in case the Optimizer prefers to start with `p`, then move on to `v`.

If that does not speed it up enough, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

After that, we can talk about building and maintaining a "summary table".  And we can probably get it down to less than 1 second.

**Charset/Collation**

> `p`.`upc` = convert(`mysql_reception`.`v`.`upc` using utf8))

Wherever possible, use the *same* `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` for any column used in a JOIN.